# Add new keys and values in a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array which has multiple keys `name` and different keys for `abteilung`:

```
{abteilung: "Research & Development", name: "Susanne Gast"}, {abteilung: "HR", name: "John Doe"}, {abteilung: "HR", name: "Joe Doe"}...
```

Now I want to add a key `target` with a unique id for every `name`. And I also want to add a key `source` with an id for every key+value `abteilung`. There are duplicates for `abteilung`.

I'm able to add the key+value `target`. But how can I add the key+value for `abteilung`

```
let linksArray = links;
let u = 0, let a = 0, ln = linksArray.length;       
for (u;u<ln;u++){   
   linksArray[u].target = u+1;
}
```

Thank your for your hints

Comment: What you have is just an array of objects, no JSON in sight. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. (If what you have in your first code block *were* JSON, it would be invalid JSON, as property names must be in double quotes in JSON.)

Comment: *"I'm able to add the key+value target. But how can I add the key+value for `abteilung`"* I don't understand. There already *is* a property called `abteilung`. You don't need to add it, it's already there.

Comment: It's not clear what you want the "source" value to be.

Comment: ok sorry, I need an unique id (key: target) for every name in the array. And i also need a key called source, which should have a unique id. Not in the same range of the target ids because I need the target, source-keys for drawing lines in a graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For assigning the `source`, you could first build a Map that has a key for every unique abteilung. The Map values can then become the sequential number. Finally perform a look-up in that Map for each object and assign the retrieved number to the `source` property:

```js
const links = [{abteilung: "Research & Development", name: "Susanne Gast"}, {abteilung: "HR", name: "John Doe"}, {abteilung: "HR", name: "Joe Doe"}];

const map = new Map(links.map(o => [o.abteilung, 0]));
Array.from(map.keys(), (abteilung, i) => map.set(abteilung, i+1));
links.forEach(o => o.source = map.get(o.abteilung));
console.log(links);
```

I did not include the assignment to `target`, as you had that working fine already.

If it is not necessary that the numbering is a sequence without gapes, but gaps are allowed, then you can also assign the sequence number during the Map construction:

```js
var links = [{abteilung: "Research & Development", name: "Susanne Gast"}, {abteilung: "HR", name: "John Doe"}, {abteilung: "HR", name: "Joe Doe"}];

let i = 0;
const map = new Map(links.map(o => [o.abteilung, i++]));
links.forEach(o => o.source = map.get(o.abteilung));
console.log(links);
```